# laravel taking data with input function

Tags: laravel

i want to take data with input function in Laravel controller.

When i write `dd($request->data)` im getting this:

```
"_token=R58UyxNckoaiL0eFSIsd434343Gsh&name_surname=sdfsadf&telephone=0505"
```

I want to take `name_surname`

I tried this code

`$request->data->input('name_surname')`

but i can not get any data. its turning null. How can i get datas. If you help me i will be glad

Comment: Documentation? you could have found your answer there... `$request->get('name_surname')` or `$request->input('name_surname')` or `$request->name_surname`. are 3 ways of reading the request data. If it is a GET : `$request->query('name_surname')` next time: Read the docs

Comment: I read all of them. All of them are not working. Its turning null.

Answer (score 0):

you can access data sent from a form using $reqeust object using `$request->input_name`

so, to take name_surname and telephone

```
$name_surname = $req->name_surname;
$telephone = $req->telephone;
```

learn more from laravel doc(https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-via-dynamic-properties)

*Also, validate user inputs before do anything*

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to make sure what are the inputs fields your are receiving and make sure input fields names

```
 dd($request->all())
```

then try this

```
$request->field_name
```